# A next book after Barrett O'Neill Elementary Differential Geometry

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, manifolds, book-recommendation, differential-forms

I have finished reading Barrett O'Neill Elementary Differential Geometry and I wish to study more on the field of Riemannian Geometry. Which book should I proceed?

Comment: 1. Lecture Notes on Elementary Topology and Geometry, Singer and Thorpe

Comment: 2. Geometry of Manifolds, Bishop and Crittenden